# Strange "No such file or directory" error in cuda-gdb

Tags: gdb, cuda

I already asked this question in the nvidia forum but never got an answer [link](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=176973m).

Every time I try to step into a kernel I get a similar error message to this:

```
__device_stub__Z10bitreversePj (__par0=0x110000) at 
/tmp/tmpxft_00005d4b_00000000-1_bitreverse.cudafe1.stub.c:10
10    /tmp/tmpxft_00005d4b_00000000-1_bitreverse.cudafe1.stub.c: No such file or directory.
in /tmp/tmpxft_00005d4b_00000000-1_bitreverse.cudafe1.stub.c
```

I tried to follow the instructions of the cuda-gdb walkthrough by the error stays.

Has somebody a tip what could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The "device stub" for `bitreverse(unsigned int*)` (whatever that is) was compiled with debug info, and it was located in `/tmp/tmpxft_00005d4b_00000000-1_bitreverse.cudafe1.stub.c` (which was likely machine-generated).

The `"No such file"` error is telling you that that file is not (or no longer) present on your system, but this is not an error; `GDB` just can't show you the source.

This should *not* prevent you from stepping further, or from setting breakpoints in other functions and continuing.

Comment: bitreverse is the name of the cuda kernel. It is a simple example from the cuda-gdb user-guide.
The cudafe.stub.c files are propably generated from the cudafe tool, but why are they deleted when the debug-information points to them. I used the nvcc flags that were explained in the cuda-gdb user guide.

Stepping over the kernel is no problem, I can debug the program normally except for the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by using -keep flag on the nvcc compiler.  This specifies that the compiler should keep all intermediate files created during the compilation, including the stub.c files created by cudafe that are needed for the debugger to step through kernel functions.  Otherwise the intermediate files seem to get deleted by default at the end of the compilation and the debugger will not be able to find them.  You can specify a directory for the intermediate files as well, and will need to point your debugger (cuda-gdb, nsight, etc) to this location.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had such problem once, but can't really remember what was it caused with. Do you use textures in your kernel? In that case you couldn't debug it.

Comment: No I don't use textures, I tried it with the sample walkthroug from the cuda-gdb user-guide.

I followed all steps correctly and this error pops up when I try to enter the kernel.